# How to integrate Recombee with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How do I integrate recombee with ASP.NET to display results in a list or grid view, as well as connect a book crossing dataset to it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question in this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recombee provides a .NET SDK (https://github.com/recombee/net-api-client).

The github page contains an example how to upload items catalog (your dataset) via it to Recombee. It also shows how the recommendations are requested.

Recombee API returns by default ids of the recommended items, but if you specify parameter `returnProperties=true` in the [recommendation requests](https://docs.recombee.com/api.html#recommendations), it will also return properties of the items, which you can use for filling your list/grid view.

Another source of information is the [Getting Started section](https://docs.recombee.com/gettingstarted.html) of the Recombee docs.

Comment: I am trying to integrate bookcrossing dataset into the C# cosole application. I have added rating file into the appliation . I am not clear which other file to inlcude. I am getting error "user does not exsists"

Comment: Previously used purchase and deatil view in csv format and it worked fine

Comment: Probably you are missing the `cascadeCreate` parameter in the interaction requests? The users/items will get created with `cascadeCreate=true`. See https://docs.recombee.com/api.html#add-detail-view.